# Как с помощью PHP 7.1 получить данные из SQLite3?

Tags: php, php7, sqlite3

В папке рядом с **index.php** у меня лежит **database.db** (**SQLite3**)

Как с помощью *PHP* я могу вытащить оттуда объект с определенным *ID*?

Работаю в *openserver* используя *PHP 7.1*

Я пытался сделать это так:

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = explode('?', $url);
    $chunks = explode("/", $url[0]);
    $idd = $chunks[2];

    if ($idd) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE id=$idd";
        $db = sqlite3::open("database.db");
        $res = $db->query($db, $sql);
        echo($res);
    }
?>
```

Но получил вот такую ошибку:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Non-static method SQLite3::open() cannot be called statically`

Comment: Вот вы используете функцию query(). И наверное можете же посмотреть пример использования этой функции в документации? Или не можете?

Comment: Перед тем как задать вопрос - всегда ищу возможные решения. Не нашел, поэтому Вы и видите мой вопрос.

Comment: ну то есть вот вы прямо открыли страницу документации к функции query() и не нашли там примера?

Comment: Опять же, банальный перевод в Google Translate выдает "Неустранимая ошибка: неперехваченная ошибка: нестатический метод SQLite3::open() не может быть вызван статически". Метод, вами вызываемый, нестатический, а вы его пытаетесь вызвать статически. Решение - ответ ниже.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = new SQLite3("database.db");
$db->query($db, $sql);
$db->close();
unset($db);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/sqlite3.query.php